# Append Iterations to a list of lists

Tags: python-3.x

```
   #Inert Objects       
dirt=Inert("dirt","filthy, dirty, dirt")
tree=Inert("trees","tall spindly trees")
rocks=Inert("rocks","scatterd rocks")

All.objects.append(dirt)
All.objects.append(tree)
All.objects.append(rocks)
```

I have a 6x6 game board and I want all 36 rooms to have their own list within the all objects list. I'm wondering if there is an easier way to append Iterations than one by one.

Also, i plan on making a code that grabs the objects for each room with

```
For object in objects:
   All.objects[(player_y+6)+player_x]
```

So 36 lists will be within one list.
Seems like a lot...
Here is my gameboard-

```
class Game (object):
    table=[[0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Comment: A shorter way to write your `Game` initialization is `table = [[0]*6 for _ in range(6)]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
All.objects.extend([
    Inert("dirt","filthy, dirty, dirt"),
    Inert("trees","tall spindly trees"),
    Inert("rocks","scatterd rocks"),
])
```

Comment: It works perfectly in my game! Tho... I'm not confident in understanding why I was able to get rid of Dirt= Tree= and Rocks= .... how am I able to call that iteration?

Comment: This just "extends" the list with three new objects, without naming those three objects.